# How to count number of an elements of an array and run a loop for that number?

Tags: php

I am trying to insert multiple name in guestname input field. So i've declared guestname as an array. After inserting some name in guestname field using separated by comma ( e.g : superman, batman, spiderman ) i get output as "guestname":["superman, batman, spiderman "]. I want to run loop counting all the values of the array and print one by one where others data (e.g email and address) will remain same.

```
<input type="text" name="guestname[]" multiple>
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="address">
<tr>
foreach(array_count_values($_POST['guestname'] as $key => $value)
{
  echo "<td>". $value."</td>";
  echo "<td>". $_POST["email"]."</td>";
  echo "<td>". $_POST["address"]."</td>";
}

</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to expload comma seprated value and then read it from data.

```
$guest = explode(",", $_POST['guestname'][0]);
foreach($guest as $value)
{
  echo "<td>". $value."</td>";
  echo "<td>". $_POST["email"]."</td>";
  echo "<td>". $_POST["address"]."</td>";
}
```

Comment: i am trying your code and getting the following error.                       (1)Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in line 19
and
(2)Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() line 20

Comment: Yes got it you are getting $_POST['guestname'] name in array like guest name = ['first,  second'] but you have to convert it to name = "first, second"

Comment: @amiHasan just check updated answer and try like that.

Comment: ohh... nice.. it's working now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Its my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(explode(',', join(',', $_POST['guestname'])) as $key => $value)
{
    ...
}
```

It's what you are loking for?

It merge all $_POST['guestname'] values into a string adding additional , and then re-explode them in array and loop in.

Example:

```
$_POST['guestname'][] = "name1, name2, name3, name4";
$_POST['guestname'][] = "name5, name6, name7";
```

return:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
name6
name7
```

Comment: let say i've 3/4 names separated by comma. i want to print the names one by one.

Comment: So my answer do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['guestname'] as $key => $value)
    {
       //your content
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code `"guestname":["superman, batman, spiderman "]` means that `"superman, batman, spiderman "` is a string. If these were an array it would be `"superman", "batman", "spiderman "`. So maybe you can use `explode` to get an array of elements.
For example

```
$guestname = explode("," , $_POST['guestname']);
```

And then

```
foreach(array_count_values($guestname as $key => $value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking something like below:

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="guestname">
 <input type="text" name="email">
 <input type="text" name="address">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['guestname'])){
   echo "<table border='1'>";
   foreach(array_filter(explode(',',$_POST['guestname'])) as $key => $value)
   {
     echo "<tr><td>". $value."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $_POST["email"]."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $_POST["address"]."</td></tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";
}

?>
```